# Exporta dados para excel com python

Tags: python

Estou tendo um problema no código feito em python, que eu to querendo importa uns dados que e retirado de um site e importa seja para excel ou para csv.

como vocês podem ver na foto, esses são os dados, muitas colunas e linhas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu consegui resolver o problema fazer dessa forma

```
for key, value in result.items():
   df = pd.DataFrame(result_format.format(key,
                               value['Cotacao'],
                               value['P/L'],
                               value['P/VP'],
                               ...
                               ))
   df.to_csv('Dados.csv')
```

porem só é pego uma linha desses dados e ainda e todos os dados fica em apenas na primeira coluna, da primeira linha.

E o que eu queria resolver era que cada informação na linha fosse separado por coluna, como eu posso resolver isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua chamada `result_format.format(key,
                               value['Cotacao'],
                               value['P/L'],
                               value['P/VP'],
                               ...
                               )`

faz exatamente o que você está pedindo - pega todos os seus dados, que normalmente vem separados, e cola todos juntos em uma única string.

E você, para cada linha lida do banco de dados, cria um novo dataframe , e um NOVO arquiv CSV, com o mesmo nome.

Você mostra os dados impressos, mas nao mostra a estrutura de dados, nem o código para impressao - no caso eu ainda tive que inferir que `result_format` é uma string com o template pra impressão.

Assim fica bem difícil dar uma resposta exata - mas você deve conseguir algo (possivelmente "virado 90 graus"), se simplesmnete passar esse seu `result` como está na chamada para o dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv('dados.csv')
```

Comment: Deu muito certo, obrigado!